# jQuery - exclude the parent of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i have to ecxlude the parent of a clicked element in a jQuery set of element ('.fav').
Does anybody have any advice for me how to do that?

```
$('.fav .favFrame').click(function(){
    $('.fav').fadeOut(400);          //exclude the .fav that child .favFrame was clicked here
});
```

Thx

Comment: you mean, let all elements of class "fav" fade out besides the element that is the parent of the element of the class "favFrame" which has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.fav .favFrame').click(function(){
    $('.fav').not($(this).parent()).fadeOut(400); //exclude the .fav that child .favFrame was clicked here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('.fav .favFrame').click(function(){
    var notThis = $('.fav').not($(this).parent());
    notThis.fadeOut(400); //fade all except this parent
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/djx2M/

Answer (score 1):

Try this(this works even if .fav is not the direct parent of favFrame):

```
$('.fav .favFrame').click(function(){     
    $('.fav').not($(this).closest(".fav")).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: couldn't you also use -- `$(this).parents('.fav')` in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.fav .favFrame').click(function() {
    var myParent = $(this).closest('.fav');
    $('.fav').not(myParent).fadeOut(400);
});
```

This way, the element you don't want to fade out doesn't get affected at all.